# For loop for multiple polygons in leafletproxy?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, polygon

I am making a visualization of hubway stops with neighborhood polygons in Boston.  Here's a scaled-down working code:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(rgdal)

#setwd
setwd("C:/Users/580048/Downloads")

#read hubway station data
hubway <- read.csv("Hubway_Stations.csv")

#read shapefiles
neighborhoods <-readOGR("C:/Users/580048/Downloads/bosneigh/Bos_neighborhoods_new.shp","Bos_neighborhoods_new")
neighborhoods <- spTransform(neighborhoods, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

#ui layout
ui <- bootstrapPage(

  #style of tags
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  tags$style(type = "text/css", 'label[for="range"] {color: white;}'),
  tags$style(type = "text/css", 'label[for="range2"] {color: white;}'),
  tags$style(type = "text/css", 'label[for="team"] {color: white;}'),
  tags$style(type = "text/css", 'label[for="away"] {color: white;}'),
  tags$style(type = "text/css", 'label {color: white;}'),


  #the map
  leafletOutput("bosmap", width = "100%", height = "100%")

)


#server functions
server <- function(input, output, session) {


  #plot static map
  output$bosmap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(randomtaxi) %>%
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.DarkMatterNoLabels", 
                       options= providerTileOptions(opacity = 0.99)) %>%

      fitBounds(-71.0, 42.3, -71.1, 42.4)    
  })

  #plot filtered cabs
  observe({
      longMark <- -71.0589
      latMark <- 42.3601
      poppy <- "Boston"
      hotBorough <- subset(neighborhoods, neighborhoods$Name %in% c("Allston"))
      totalBorough <- subset(neighborhoods, neighborhoods$Name %in% c("Back Bay"))

    leafletProxy("bosmap", data = hubway) %>%
      clearShapes() %>% clearMarkers %>% clearPopups() %>%

        addPolygons(data = subset(neighborhoods, neighborhoods$Name %in% c(toString(neighborhoods$Name[1]))),
                    stroke = FALSE, 
                    color = "red",
                    smoothFactor = 0.5,
                    fillOpacity = 0.3,
                    popup = toString(neighborhoods$Name[1])) %>%

      addPopups(longMark, latMark, poppy,
                options = popupOptions(closeButton = FALSE)
      ) %>%
      addCircles(~hubway$long_, 
                 ~hubway$lat,
                 radius = 200,
                 weight = 20,
                 stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 0.5)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What I want to do is create a for loop within leaftletproxy() to loop through and create INDIVIDUAL polygons for each of Boston's 26 neighborhoods -- something like this:

```
leafletProxy("bosmap", data = hubway) %>%
  clearShapes() %>% clearMarkers %>% clearPopups() %>%

  for(i in 1:26){

    addPolygons(data = subset(neighborhoods, neighborhoods$Name %in% c(toString(neighborhoods$Name[i]))),
                stroke = FALSE, 
                color = "red",
                smoothFactor = 0.5,
                fillOpacity = 0.3,
                popup = toString(neighborhoods$Name[i])) %>%

  }

  addPopups(longMark, latMark, poppy,
            options = popupOptions(closeButton = FALSE)
  ) %>% ...(and so on)
```

But for some reason, leafletProxy() doesn't seem to like putting for loops inside it -- is there any easier way to plot a number of different polygons that I can attach different popups, colors, and values to?

Bos neighborhood file here: https://data.cityofboston.gov/City-Services/Boston-Neighborhood-Shapefiles/af56-j7tb

hubway stations: http://bostonopendata.boston.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/ee7474e2a0aa45cbbdfe0b747a5eb032_4

Comment: I suspect that it is the `%>%` operator that does not support for loop inside it? If so, you can break the chain in the middle, and use for loops, and then use chain again if you need.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with @warmoverflow that `%>% for(){}` is not the proper way to use `%>%` with `for`.  In general, I don't think using `for` in a pipeline is really good practice, but here is the pattern to do what you suggest.

```
library(magrittr)

"test" %>%
{
  for(i in 1:26){
    . <- paste0(.,i)
  }
  return(.)
}
```

so in your example, you could do, but I'll propose a "better" way later.

```
leafletProxy("bosmap", data = hubway) %>%
  clearShapes() %>% clearMarkers %>% clearPopups() %>%

  {
    for(i in 1:26){

      . <- addPolygons(.,data = subset(neighborhoods, neighborhoods$Name %in% c(toString(neighborhoods$Name[i]))),
                  stroke = FALSE, 
                  color = "red",
                  smoothFactor = 0.5,
                  fillOpacity = 0.3,
                  popup = toString(neighborhoods$Name[i])
            )
    }
    return(.)
  } %>%
  addPopups(longMark, latMark, poppy,
            options = popupOptions(closeButton = FALSE)
  ) %>% ...(and so on)
```

I think this is a better way to handle.

```
leafletProxy("bosmap", data = hubway) %>%
  clearShapes() %>% clearMarkers %>% clearPopups() %>%
  addPolygons(
    data = neighborhoods[1:26,],
    stroke = FALSE,
    color = "red",
    smoothFactor = 0.5,
    fillOpacity = 0.3,
    popup = ~Name
  )
```

Comment: When I try to do this the better way all of my polygons try to connect to each other so I have polygons in germany connecting to those in the U.S. Any way around this?

Comment: no function to return from, jumping to top level